# Creating C# .dll called by VBA

Tags: c#, vba, dll, com, typelib

Previously I saw from somewhere else (I can't revisit that source now as I was fired from the company) a piece of C# coding which create a dll. And that .dll can be called directly by Excel VBA's Reference. (Not by calling reference from .tlb)

I tried to replicate it but fails, warning me that "Can't add a reference
to the specified file" when I tried to add the .dll reference. But its OK to add the .tlb reference.

Is there anyway to add the .dll reference instead of .tlb?

Answer (score 0):

One usually refers to the libraries as specific Functions or Commands (void functions) explicitly in VBA code.

i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915.aspx

You could also use Visual Studio tools for Office, which gives you much more power than a dll reference and VBA.

Also, you could made an add-in without VSTO, by doing the below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173189(VS.80).aspx